# Especificar ratio de la imagen a mostrar en Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Hay alguna función java o atributo en xml del `imageView` para especificar el ratio de la imagen?
es decir `16:9`, `3:2`, `4:3` etc...

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/about_background_header"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:contentDescription="default desc" />
```

La imagen original es en formato `16:9` pero desearía si se puede mostrar en `3:2` etc...

Comment: Esto te puede servir, esta fácil de implementar, ojo con las correcciones de los comentarios de abajo.  https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/2856179

Comment: Como comentario, el url que comparte nuestro amigo @Bourne tiene un buen ejemplo, al yo cambiaría la linea aspectRatio = a.getFloat(R.styleable.AspectRatioImageView_aspectRatio, DEFAULT_ASPECT_RATIO);  por un calculo para obtener el aspectRatio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me parece que te refieres al "aspecto", (Aspect Ratio). Una propiedad así sería genial ya que por las distintas medidas y densidades que se manejan en los dispositivos Android, puede desplegarse correctamente en todos los dispositivos.

No existe tal propiedad, lo más cercano es usar la propiedad  [adjustViewBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setAdjustViewBounds(boolean)) :

```
android:adjustViewBounds = "true"
```

o

```
myImageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

Si quieres realizarlo programaticamente sería calcular las medidas en base a el aspecto. El "aspectRatio", se calcularía por ejemplo si defines un aspecto 4:3 sería 3/4 = 0.75.

```
aspectRatio = 0.75;
myHeight = (int) (myWidth * aspectRatio);
```

De esta forma obtendrías la altura determinada por el aspecto.

Comment: Hola me acabo de topar con eso https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html parece ser interesante el uso de ese layout

Answer (score 0):

Gracias al comentario de @bourne y la respuesta de @Elenasys he creado lo siguiente, hay trozos cogidos por allí.

Función para obtener la altura teniendo en cuenta el ratio con su anchura.

```
public int getHeightAspectRatio(float ratio, int width) {
        return (int) (width / ratio);
    }
```

Y su uso

```
imageHeader = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_header);
imageHeader.setImageResource(R.drawable.about_background_header);

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

/*  16:9        3:2        4:3        1:1        3:4        2:3          */

android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = imageHeader.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width =  metrics.widthPixels;
layoutParams.height = getHeightAspectRatio(16f/9f, metrics.widthPixels);
imageHeader.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```